# vba - scan documents for macro and replace macro text?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba

I'm presented with a puzzle. Where I work there are a huge amount of Word templates which all contains an autonew eventhandle which contains some errors. And this error lies within all templates. And I was wondering if there might be a way of scanning a directory for templates which contains this macro and change the macro code slightly?

Could this be possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can access the VBA project of any document using:

```
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
```

Your project must have a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility".

To run the code, you must enable the "Trust Access to Visual Basic Project" option in Word, using

> Tools->Macro->Security (Trusted
>   Publishers tab)

The `VBComponents` collection contains all the standard modules, class modules, forms and "document" modules that the project contains. If you Google it, you'll find plenty of help on how to access/modify them.

**EDIT**: OK, some more detail. This method will search all the `VbComponents` of a document looking for a method with the specified name, and perform a search/replace within the first one it finds.

```
Public Sub ReplaceInProject(ByVal oDocument As Document, ByVal strMethodName As String, ByVal strFindText As String, ByVal strReplaceWithText As String)

    ' For each module (of any type - could use oVbComponent.Type to restrict
    ' this to certain types of module)

    Dim oVbComponent As VBComponent
    For Each oVbComponent In oDocument.VBProject.VBComponents

        Dim oCodeModule As CodeModule
        Set oCodeModule = oVbComponent.CodeModule

        ' See if we can find the method in this module

        Dim ixStartLine As Long
        ixStartLine = FindMethodStartLine(oCodeModule, strMethodName)

        If ixStartLine > 0 Then

            ' Get all the text of the method

            Dim numLines As Long
            numLines = oCodeModule.ProcCountLines(strMethodName, vbext_pk_Proc)

            Dim strLines As String
            strLines = oCodeModule.Lines(ixStartLine, numLines)

            ' Do the find/replace

            strLines = Replace(strLines, strFindText, strReplaceWithText)

            ' Replace the method text.

            oCodeModule.DeleteLines ixStartLine, numLines

            oCodeModule.InsertLines ixStartLine, strLines

        End If

    Next oVbComponent

End Sub

Private Function FindMethodStartLine(ByVal oCodeModule As CodeModule, ByVal strMethodName As String) As Long

    FindMethodStartLine = 0

    ' ProcStartLine will raise an error if the method is not found;
    ' we'll just ignore the error and return -1

    On Error Resume Next
    FindMethodStartLine = oCodeModule.ProcStartLine(strMethodName, vbext_pk_Proc)

End Function
```

Note that this will only work with `Sub` and `Function` methods, not property `Get/Set/Let` because I'm using `vbext_pk_Proc`. It's a PITA that you need to be explicit about this. Frankly, the whole API for the `CodeModule` component seems almost designed to frustrate. For example, while the `VbComponent` object has a `Find` method (which you'd think was a convenient way to find the text you're looking for), it actually returns `True` or `False`(!). Useful, I don't think!

The designers of this API must have had a really bad hangover when they did this.

Comment: Thanks :) So I've added this to my project and imported Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, but do you know how I can load a macro from a Word document into a textbox in my Visual Studio project? And then edit the text and then save it back again?

Or would it be better to generate a Word file with the macro and then just copy the macro from that document over to the next one?