# how programatically know excel file has macro file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

i have a one 2003 excel file. using ofc.exe file i have converted the 2003 excel file in to 2007 exls file.

now my problem is before convert the file can i know the excel file is a macro excel file in c#.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742044/vba-scan-documents-for-macro-and-replace-macro-text/1742745#1742745) I found that using `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponent` seems to be what you want.

A similar question was asked on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/officegeneral/thread/e3fbdb11-dce9-46a8-9105-6d3ab83e6103) albeit that one concerns Visio not Excel. I'm sure you can adapt the code accordingly.

Further on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006328/programmatically-determine-if-an-excel-file-xls-contains-macros) asks exactly the same as you do. Albeit this answers does not seem to cover C#...

Over [at the eggheadcafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32135161/programmatically-determine-if-workbook-contains-macros-in-excel-20.aspx) one user suggests using this code snippet to loop through all VB-components:

```
Sub Test()
  If bHasMacros(ActiveWorkbook) Then
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name & " has macros."
  End If
End Sub

Function bHasMacros(ByRef wkbBook As Workbook) As Boolean
  Dim cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent
  For Each cmpComponent In wkbBook.VBProject.VBComponents
    If cmpComponent.CodeModule.CountOfLines > 1 Then
      bHasMacros = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next cmpComponent
End Function
```

Comment: but my application is in c#. how can i use this code? can you please suggest me.